# Claim "stolen" page on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a client with a company which wants to create a Facebook page. However, someone has already taken my clients company name on Facebook and established a page there.

The page has not been used for anything yet, but people have already started to "Like" the page, thinking it's the page of my client. The client has complained to Facebook and they have not considered this to be a violation. The company is a rather well established institution in my country.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and have advice on the next step to take in such a case?

Appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some information here on how to Report Claims of Intellectual Property Infringement;

http://www.facebook.com/legal/copyright.php

And a reporting form here;

http://www.facebook.com/legal/copyright.php?noncopyright_notice=1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this page has been established to mimic your client's brand? Companies may have the exact same names and be active in completely different branches of economy. The name is not enough. What about your client's logo and visual identity - is it also used by the page?

Comment: Yes, it's established to mimic the clients name, but it's actually not a brand violation.

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific - was it established to use your client's reputation to bring traffic or for poaching in hope your client would "buy" it? Could you point a link to this page so that we could see what we are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

facebook allows users to create what you could call a 'tribute page' for companies that it likes , for instance i might create a page for 'mcdonalds north pole' and there would be nothing illegal about it as long as i am not posing as the official owner of 'mcdonalds north pole'
What you can check do is Mark the page as the official xyz company page and request facebook to acknowledge that you are the real owners